# Unexpected output of printf for the float value 10.1

Tags: c, formatting

Can anybody explain what's the difference between %g and %f.
I know about %0.2f as i understood it prints after dot 2 decimal places only!
I tried this code...

```
int main()
{
   float val = 10.0;
   printf("<%g><%0.2g><%0.4g><%f><%0.2f>", val, val, val, val, val);

   return 0;
}
//giving : <10><10><10><10.000000><10.00>

//If i give 10.1 instead!
int main()
{
   float val = 10.1;
   printf("<%g><%0.2g><%0.4g><%f><%0.2f>", val, val, val, val, val);

   return 0;
}
//giving : <10.1><10><10.1><10.000000><10.00>
// How come here i got for %g    --> 10.1
//                         %0.2g --> 10
//                         %0.4g --> 10.1
```

Please somebody clarify me!

Comment: Simple: your program has UB because the signature of `main()` is incorrect.

Comment: H2CO3 means that your program has undefined behavior because the declaration of main is incorrect (should return int instead of void).

Comment: @H2CO3, Nop! I checked it with int return type also! I'm getting same!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Nop! I changed and checked again! same output!

Answer (score 0):

Linux Programmers' Manual for `%g` and `%G`:

> The  double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or E for G conversions).  **The precision specifies the number of significant
>   digits.**  If the precision is missing, 6 digits are given; if the precision is zero, it is treated as 1.  Style e is used if the exponent from its
>   conversion is less than -4 or greater than  or  equal
>   to the precision.  Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it
>   is followed by at least one digit.

Thus, before the . is the field width; after . is the maximum number number of significant  digits in the result, but trailing zeroes are removed. 10.10000 with 4 significant digits is 10.10, but the trailing zero removal results in 10.1. With 2 significant digits, the result is 10. And `%g` equals `%.6g`.

Notice however the second part:

> Style e is used if the exponent from its
>   conversion is less than -4 or greater than  or  equal
>   to the precision.

This means that 100 formatted with `%0.2g` results in `1e+02`

Answer (score 0):

Have run a copy of your code in Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler environment.

Overall, %g has two possible behaviors, one when the exponent is greater than or equal to -4, as 1*10^-4 = 0.0001 and the other when the exponent is < -4, as in 0.00001.

```
    // Microsoft C compiler "handles" void main()
    void main()
    {
      // Note. Exponent is 1
      float val = 10.0;
      printf("\n<%g><%0.2g><%0.4g><%f><%0.2f>", val, val, val, val, val);

      // Exponent is still 1
      val = 10.1;
      printf("\n<%g><%0.2g><%0.4g><%f><%0.2f>", val, val, val, val, val);

      // Exponent is -5, and the %g format specifier behaves as you expect
      val = 0.000011;
      printf("\n<%g><%0.2g><%0.4g><%f><%0.2f>", val, val, val, val, val);

      // output == <1.1e-005><1.1e-005><1.1e-005><0.000011><0.00>

    }
```

Your code is behaving as documented by the ANSI C standard, its performance has absolutely nothing to do with how you coded something as unrelated to `printf` as the `main()` statement.